# Ngen hard binding (DependencyAttribute) usage

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, ngen

**Some context**

When my application is installed, the installer calls Ngen for all assemblies it deploys. This was done to reduce startup time and it works quite well (it reduces the time from around 22 sec to around 14 sec on my machine). It is a .NET 4.0 x86 WPF application, uses around 40 assemblies (most of them third-party), the size of all assemblies is around 45 MB.

I now applied some [DependencyAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dependencyattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to my code to enable hard binding ([explanation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). The reason to do this is to already load some third-party assemblies during startup that would otherwise not be loaded until the user opens the first data entry window. Yes I know that this will slow down the startup time of my application, but this is ok if it reduces the time that is needed for opening the first data entry window.

**The questions**

1) Is there any way to check if a loaded native image was loaded as a hard binding or normal/soft binding?

2) (If the answer to the first question is yes, I can check this myself.) If I have AssemblyA that defines `[assembly: Dependency("AssemblyB", LoadHint.Always)]` and AssemblyB that defines `[assembly: Dependency("AssemblyC", LoadHint.Always)]`, will loading AssemblyA also load AssemblyC with a hard binding (assuming all three have valid native images)? Or do I need to specify direct hard dependencies to all dependend assemblies? Because if I do a `ngen display /verbose` those indirect dependencies are not listed as direct hard dependencies, only as hard dependencies of a dependency.

3) I've just found out that I can't define an assembly as a hard dependency if that assembly isn't directly used in my assembly (message from `ngen install /verbose`: WARNING: Cannot hardbind to ThirdPartyAssemblyB because it is not loaded). So my project references ThirdPartyAssemblyA and ThirdPartyAssemblyB, but doesn't use any classes from ThirdPartyAssemblyB. But ThirdPartyAssemblyB is still needed at runtime because ThirdPartyAssemblyA uses it. Using the .NET Reflector I can see that the compiler removed my reference to ThirdPartyAssemblyB. And using `ngen display /verbose` I can see that my assembly doesn't have a direct dependency on ThirdPartyAssemblyB, neither hard nor soft. Of course it still has an indirect dependency over ThirdPartyAssemblyA (which is a hard dependency), but since ThirdPartyAssemblyA doesn't have a hard dependency on ThirdPartyAssemblyB, this doesn't help. Do I really need to create some dummy code that directly references ThirdPartyAssemblyB just to get a hard binding on it?

4) For some reason `ngen install MyAssembly /verbose` prints the following warning: "WARNING: Cannot hardbind to PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 because dependency does not have a native image (check FusLogVw for reason)". But I **do** have a native image of PresentationFramework and using Fuslogvw I can see that it is loaded at runtime. After installing the native images `ngen display /verbose` even lists PresentationFramework as a hard dependency of my assembly. So what does this warning mean?

Comment: According to the docs assemblies will load there dependencies automatically.  Now I have never had to confirm it happens but maybe use filemon to observe what is been loaded on startup?

Comment: @Zonder I've used Process Explorer to check that the assemblies are loaded (they are). The question is how to check if assemblies that are also loaded if there is no hard binding (because they are used during startup) are loaded with a hard binding. This would be especially interesting for the PresentationFramework assembly since the hard binding to that throws a warning as written in question 4.